# Permission denied when exporting to CSV in R

Tags: r, export

Here is the code I tried, I tried to ways. Basically I'm just wondering about the permission denied part.

```
 data <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol=2)
 write.csv(data,"C:/Users/brian_000/Documents")
```

Error:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
 In addition: Warning message:
 In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
   cannot open file 'C:/Users/brian_000/Documents': Permission denied
   write.csv(data, file="C:/Users/brian_000/Documents")
  Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
 cannot open the connection
 In addition: Warning message:
 In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/brian_000/Documents': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 14):

`C:/Users/brian_000/Documents` is (presumably) a directory, so you can't write to it like it is a file. Instead, write to a file like `C:/Users/brian_000/Documents/myfile.csv`.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error trying to execute:

> tip_data <- read.csv('my_tipdata.csv', header = TRUE)

**Reason being I had the file open in Excel.** Once I closed the file, it executed properly.